# quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

A garden is in the shape of a rectangle, $20$m by $8$m. Around the outside is a border of uniform width and in the middle is a square pond. The area which is not occupied by either border or pond is 1$24 m^2$. Letting the width of border be $x$cm, find the equation. Solve the equation to find the value of $x$.

Comment: Did you try sketching a diagram?

Comment: @Jack I have tried but the diagram is weird

Comment: The question is unclear. Since the problem has an infinite number of solutions if the pond does not touch the border (can you see why?) I will assume it does. In terms of $x$, what would the area of the border be? The square? From that you should be able to form an equation.

Comment: Do you have some other information about the side of the pond, in particular about its relation with $x$?

Comment: @Anatoly no but the answer is 3x^2-56x+36=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided in the last comment works if we assume that the side of the square pond is equal to $x$ as well. In this case, the rectangle without the borders has sides $20-2x$ and $8-2x$, and the area of the pond is $x^2$. Thus

$$(20-2x)(8-2x)-x^2=124$$

$$160-56x+4x^2-x^2=124$$

and then

$$3x^2-56x+36=0$$

whose solutions are $x=\frac{2}{3}$ (realistic for the context of the problem) and $18$.